# Ajax request is called too many times ( ajax loading gifs stops)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having a problem doing an ajax request with the following code.

**Ajax Request**

```
function doRequest(url, hostname) {

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    data: 'hostname=' + hostname,
    error: function () { alert('erro'); $('#loading').hide(); },
    success: function (data) {

        $('#content').html(data);
        $('#loading').hide();
    },
    beforeSend: function () {
        alert(1);
        $('#content').html(""); 
        $('#loading').show();
    }
});

return false;
}
```

**Search Form**

```
<form action="/Home/SearchMachine" class="form-wrapper cf" id="search">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Hostname..." id="hostname" required>
        <button type="submit">Validar</button>
    </form>
```

**Click event**

```
$('#search').submit(function() { 
    if (validateSearchForm()) { 
          $('#val_error').hide();  
          doRequest('/Home/SearchMachine',$('#hostname').val());
     } 
    else
    $('#val_error').show(); 

    return false;    
});
```

In the first request I get one `alert(1)`, in the second two `alert(1)`, in the next four `alert(1)` that are triggered in `success` function. I made too many tests but I did not find the solution. After many requests, the ajax loading gif stops, as well as the browser.

Comment: And how are you calling that function ?

Comment: What is the data that you get as the response and show us the html code

Comment: I've edited the description of the problem. Do u find the problem?

Comment: data received from the controller is an partial view with html code (only a table).

Comment: I agree with other posters, nothing in the code you've posted would cause an issue. Best guess is binding the event handler more than once.

Answer (score 1):

I made a quick test with your code and a test service. I'm not able to reproduce the problem. Each callback only happens once per click.

```
doRequest('http://headers.jsontest.com/', $('#hostname').val());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QUXJU/

Are you re-binding submit somehow after each click?

Answer (score 0):

Give an `onSubmit` to the form for transparency..

**Form** :

```
<form action="/Home/SearchMachine"  onSubmit="submit_form(); return false;" class="form-wrapper cf" id="search">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Hostname..." id="hostname" required>
        <button type="submit">Validar</button>
    </form>
```

**Function**:

```
function submit_form()
{
    if (validateSearchForm()) { 
          $('#val_error').hide();  
          doRequest('/Home/SearchMachine',$('#hostname').val());
     } 
    else
    $('#val_error').show(); 
}
```